# error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant for characters selected from a string literal

Tags: c, gcc

I get this error with this code compiling with gcc 8.2:

```
#define literal "string"
switch(i) {
case literal[0]:
break;
}
```

Could the compiler reduce the expression literal[0] to 's' in my example?

Comment: I am using the C11 standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C2011 6.4.8.2p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.2p3) requires each case label's expression to be an *integer constant expression*.  Integer constant expressions are a restricted subset of constant expressions, defined in §[6.6p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p6).  String literals may not appear in integer constant expressions.

6.4.8.2p3 is a "constraints" paragraph, so this program is ill-formed.

So the answer to your question, as literally asked, is: the compiler *could* reduce `"string"[0]` to `'s'`, but it's not allowed to; it is required to reject your program instead.

Comment: @Remy Yes, this hasn't changed since C89. There is a version of the original ANSI C standard available from the Wayback Machine: <https://web.archive.org/web/20151125170555/http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt>. It appears to have essentially the same requirement on case labels in section "3.6.4.2 The switch statement", and essentially the same definition of the restricted subset of constant expressions in section "3.4 CONSTANT EXPRESSIONS" (note they're called _integral_ constant expressions in this edition). But, unlike N1570, it's a txt file so I can't link to specific sections.

Answer (score 1):

In that example, in theory yes it could.

However, obviously it does not. So you have to write your code differently anyway.

To expand on Florian's answer:

In C++ using a literal or `constexpr` this does apparently work.

An example which compiles with `g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -O3 -DNDEBUG -flto -march=native -Wall -Wextra -Werror cpp-switch-test.cpp -o cpp-switch-test`

```
int main(int, char *argv[]) {
    constexpr char s[] = "string";
    switch (argv[1][0]) {
        case *s:
            break;
        case s[4]:
            break;
        case "test"[0]:
        default:
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A C compiler may treat additional expressions as integer constant expressions, so the compiler could treat this as a constant as well.

You could use a current C++ compiler instead: C++11 and later treat such expressions as constant.

Comment: 6.6p10 allows additional forms of constant expressions, but I don't see any flex in the rules for _integer_ constant expressions?

Comment: @zwol: If the Committee intended that 6.6p10 only apply to non-integer constant expressions, why do you suppose that they didn't say that?  If e.g. code declares an automatic object `char foo[(int)(15.0/3.0)];`, is anything useful gained by requiring that a compiler keep track of the fact that even though `foo` will always be a 5-character array, and it can be allocated like one, `sizeof foo` isn't an integer constant expression, and code must not be allowed to jump branch past its declaration?

Comment: @supercat Since both "constant expression" and "integer constant expression" are defined terms in the C standard, the sentence "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions" does not license the implementation to accept other forms of integer constant expressions. I cannot speculate on the committee's motives for not allowing other forms of ICEs, but I would point out that VLAs were shoehorned into C99 somewhat clumsily and this wouldn't be the only place where they interact poorly with apparently-unrelated requirements.

Comment: @zwol: I would interpret the Standard as saying that the set of constructs implementations are required to accept in contexts requiring integer constant expressions is smaller than the set that would be required in other contexts.  Among other things, a compiler which can't afford to have a floating-point library in memory while it compiles could process `static float foo=20.0/5.0;` by generating code that would perform the division prior to the execution of `main`.  Given `struct foo{int bar[20.0/5.0],boz;};`, however, such deferred evaluation would require run-time patching lots of code.

Comment: @supercat That's all perfectly true but doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question of whether "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions" implies "An implementation may accept other forms of integer constant expressions".  My interpretation is that it doesn't, simply because "integer constant expression" and "constant expression" are independent terms in the standard.